# How can i lock the screen orientation to portrait mode in react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, android-orientation

How can I lock the screen mode to portrait mode in [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html)?

React navigation version I am using: 4.0.10

Here is my navigation structure

```
const AppNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
    Initialize: {
        //screen: SplashScreen,
        screen: Login,
    },
    ApplicationIntro: {
        screen: ApplicationIntro,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        },
    },
    Auth: AuthNavigation,
    Home: Home,
});
```

There is nothing in the documentation on handing the screen orientation by passing paramerters through `navigationOptions` or `defaultNavigationOptions`.

Is there anyway to lock the screen mode to "portrait" without using any other library?

Comment: do you mean you want your application only be portrait mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to set the orientation portrait mode, add this piece of code `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to activity tag in android manifest file just like this

In the manifest, set this for all your activities:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so react-navigation is providing orientation property. So you can use react-native-orientation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation) but as you can see its not updated from last two years and its listener also not work properly sometime. So, then i used **react-native-orientation-locker** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker) and I don;t find any issues with this one.
so you can use react-native-orientation-locker (please check spelling while installing using yarn as they misspelled it).

Comment: Yes, I think I will not use any library for that.